# viewpager fragments not receiving otto events from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, event-bus, otto

I have an activity with a Viewpager. my viewpager has several fragments. i want to send Otto event to a fragment when it is selected, thus i implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`

```
     @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
     currentPosition = position;
    switch (position){
      case 0:
        EventBus.getInstance().post(new TypeEvent());
        break;
      case 1:
        EventBus.getInstance().post(new InternalEvent());
        break;
    }
  }
```

Inside my first fragment

```
@Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
  EventBus.getInstance().register(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getInstance().unregister(this);
  }

  @Subscribe
  public void init(TypeEvent event){
    Logger.d("type event received");
    //do something.......
  }
```

My event bus class

```
    public class EventBus extends Bus {

   private static EventBus eventBus;

    public static EventBus getInstance(){
        if(eventBus == null){
          eventBus = new EventBus();
        }
        return eventBus;
      }
    }
```

The problem is my fragments are not receiving events. what could be the problem?

Comment: Event is fire when you call post method?

Comment: @sasikumar i got to know the cause of the problem. see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when the event comes, the eventbus hasn't been registed yet, especilly at the Fragment's first initialization time.

So u can let `EventBus.getInstance().register(this);` be called at `onAttach()` and unregister at `onDettach`.

Comment: i got to know the cause of the problem. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `onPageSelected(int position)` method wasn't being called even after setting adapter on my viewpager and caling `viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);` in my activity `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pm);
    Toolbar toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pmViewpager);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition);
  }
```

i had to manually call `onPageSelected(int position)` through viewpager's `post()` method.

```
viewPager.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            onPageSelected(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
          }
        });
```

Thus my overall `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` looked like this

```
@Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pm);
        Toolbar toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pmViewpager);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition);

viewPager.post(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                onPageSelected(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
              }
            });
      }
```

All other pages(fragments) are receiving the events because `onpageSelected()` will be called when on scroll away from the first page.
it's only the first page that wasn't receiving the event.